# Getting Invalid Element State Exception

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework, exception

I am trying to clear text from `<div>` section using XPath using the below line.

```robot
Clear Element Text    xpath=//*[@id="intro-overlay"]/div
```

I am getting below Error:

> InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element
>   must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Can anyone please help me how to fix this.

Comment: you may need to hack it to be editable before you can clear it.

Comment: It is also possible that you improperly located your text field.

Comment: @Yu Zhang - How can we hack it ? Any examples will be helpful.

Comment: @Alexey - I am logging the variable. I get - "full-height full-width display-flex flex-direction-column align-items-center position-fixed". If I delete this manually, it works. So, I am trying to see how can I edit/delete the text.

Comment: A possible scenario could be the element is being obscured by another when clicking, or perhaps not being visible on the DOM. Check the state of the element at the time of interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are performing the action on wrong element.

**`<div>` tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document. The  element is often used as a container for other HTML elements to style them with CSS or to perform certain tasks with JavaScript.**

The `clear` command works on textbox (`<input>`) or textarea. So make sure you have located the correct textbox for clearing the text

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I am not clearing the textbox value. It's part of the HTML div section which has style and I am trying to maipulate/overwrite the style property.

Comment: @qaautomation2018, can you share the exact html code for that element

Comment: This is the HTML section. <div name="fixed-page" class="full-height full-width display-flex flex-direction-column align-items-center position-fixed" style="top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 9;">. I am trying for this -->   <div name="fixed-page" class="full-height full-width display-flex flex-direction-column align-items-center position-fixed" style="">

Comment: @qaautomation2018, there should be input tag. is it possible to share the url. because the content you have shared is not enough to get the things